CMake Error, Could not find a package configuration file provided by "unofficial-sqlite3"
1> [CMake] -- Running vcpkg install - done
1> [CMake] -- Could NOT find unofficial-sqlite3 (missing: unofficial-sqlite3_DIR)
1> [CMake] CMake Error at C:/Users/user1/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:859 (_find_package):
1> [CMake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "unofficial-sqlite3" with any of
1> [CMake]   the following names:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     unofficial-sqlite3Config.cmake
1> [CMake]     unofficial-sqlite3-config.cmake
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   Add the installation prefix of "unofficial-sqlite3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
1> [CMake]   "unofficial-sqlite3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "unofficial-sqlite3"
1> [CMake]   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
1> [CMake]   installed.
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   src/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!


My folder structure looks like this:
Setup/
   
    build/
    src/
       CMakeLists.txt
       main.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
    vcpkg.json

My vcpkg.json looks like this:
{
    "name": "whatever",
    "version-string": "whatever",
    "dependencies": [
        "fltk",
        "protobuf",
        "sqlite3",
        "boost"
    ],
    "builtin-baseline": "6f1ddd6b6878e7e66fcc35c65ba1d8feec2e01f8"
}


My top level CMakeLists.txt looks like:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/Users/user1/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

project(
    NETWORKING
    VERSION 0.00
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

add_subdirectory(src)

and my src/CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

add_executable(main main.cpp)

message("DIR IS: ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/x64-Debug/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/ CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(FLTK HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/x64-Debug/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/ CONFIG REQUIRED )
find_package(protobuf HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/x64-Debug/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/ CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE fltk fltk_gl fltk_forms fltk_images)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE protobuf::libprotoc protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE unofficial::sqlite3::sqlite3)

I open Setup/ with Visual Studio, then I generate using the IDE's intellisense suggestion.
The output gives me the error I mentioned above.
Edit:
After being suggested to use HINTS passed into find_package.
I get the following output:
-- Running vcpkg install - done
1> [CMake] DIR IS: C:/Users/user1/source/repos/NewSetu[
1> [CMake] -- Could NOT find unofficial-sqlite3 (missing: unofficial-sqlite3_DIR)
1> [CMake] -- Could NOT find FLTK (missing: FLTK_DIR)
1> [CMake] -- Could NOT find protobuf (missing: protobuf_DIR)
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done (3.1s)
1> [CMake] CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:10 (target_link_libraries):
1> [CMake]   Target "main" links to:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     protobuf::libprotoc
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     * There is a typo in the target name.
1> [CMake]     * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
1> [CMake]     * An ALIAS target is missing.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
1> [CMake] CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.


I have unofficial-sqlite3-config.cmake in the vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\share\unofficial-sqlite3 folder in my vcpkg however I am using a 2+ year old vcpkg snapshot because of an  production project dependency and I haven't move to manifest mode yet.

For me it's also in build/x64-Debug/vcpkg_installed/x64--windows/share/unofficial-sqlite3/ but it doesn't find it. I even tried changing the CMakeLists.txt at the top level to have set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=path/to/vcpkg_installed/) as I understand that tells CMake to look in these directories? But it still doesn't work.

@Tsyvarev yeah it didn't change anything. Still gives me the same error. (As I was passing the correct toolchain file on the IDE CMakeSettings.json) (But the rest of that file is unmodified really and is left as default)

@Tsyvarev right above where I copied the error, it says "Running vcpkg install - done". Does that mean it activated correctly?

Sorry, didn't notice CONFIG keyword, With that keyword the output from vcpkg toolchain about not-found package is the same as with regular CMake toolchain. Still, it will be better to include other vcpkg-related output into the question post.

Give a hint to find_package, may work. In find_package there should be HINTS option.

@kiner_shah so like
find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/x64-windows/ CONFIG REQUIRED)? It still doesn't work.
